# PHP transform coordinates into array of arrays and back to variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, coordinates

I need to transform some kml coordinates (x,y,z) into an (x,y) array to use with a php function, and get then back into a variable to use with google maps.

```
$pontos = "224,250,0 244,232,0 231,262,0 248,229,0 224,250,0";
```

Needs to be transformed to this:

```
$pontos = array(
    array('x'=>224,'y'=>250),
    array('x'=>244,'y'=>232),
    array('x'=>231,'y'=>262),
    array('x'=>248,'y'=>229),
    array('x'=>224,'y'=>250)
);
```

And it will be used with a certain function:

```
simplify($pontos);
```

This function will return a simplified array of points like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [x] => 224 [y] => 250 ) 
[1] => Array ( [x] => 231 [y] => 262 ) 
[2] => Array ( [x] => 224 [y] => 250 ) 
)
```

And this array will need to be transformed back into a variable, like this:

```
$pontos = "224,250,0 231,262,0 224,250,0";
```

Can someone point me a direction of how I can achieve that?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And all these steps are mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both conversions are specific implements using `array_map()`:

```
$pontos = "224,250,0 244,232,0 231,262,0 248,229,0 224,250,0";

// convert to
$xy = array_map(function($item) {
    return ['x' => strtok($item, ','), 'y' => strtok(',')];
}, explode(' ', $pontos));

// convert back
$pontos = join(' ', array_map(function($item) {
    return sprintf('%d,%d,0', $item['x'], $item['y']);
}, $xy));
```

Comment: Really nice usage of `strtok`

Comment: Made some minor changes to work with php 5.2 (client's server :/). It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would go about doing that:

```
//To convert it into a 2D array    
$pontos = explode(" ",$pontos);
for($i=0;$i<count($pontos);$i++){
     $temp = array_splice(explode(",",$pontos[$i]),2);
     $pontos[$i]['x'] = $temp[0];
     $pontos[$i]['y'] = $temp[1];
}
```

There is no way to convert it back, as the "z" coordinate will have been removed, so you would need to store the string in another variable beforehand before converting it.

```
$old = $pontos;
//do converting stuff
//.....
//convert back by doing:
$pontos = $old
```

However, assuming the z will always be 0, you *can* reverse it like this:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($pontos);$j++){
     $pontos[$j] = implode(",",$pontos[$j]);
     $pontos[$j] .= ",0"
}
$pontos = implode(" ",$pontos);
```

Note: I have not run this code, so it **may** have a few errors (probably not though).  If it doesn't work, comment and I'll update the answer accordingly.